# How trigger an action via ajax automatically without click after 2 minutes the HTML is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I need to call an action automatically via ajax to refresh the current page after 2 minutes it has been loaded.

I know to trigger an ajax call as a URL link using:

```
<s:url id="ajax" action="AjaxAction!ajaxCall"/>
<sx:a href="%{ajax}" targets="divAjax" loadingText="Loading...">Ajax Call</sx:a>

<sx:div id="divAjax"></sx:div>
```

What I am looking for is to specify 120 seconds in order to trigger automatically an ajax call that will refresh the view (webpage) without clicking anything.

Appreciate your help

Comment: WHY do you need to call it after exactly 2 minutes? Seems like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Nevertheless, see [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) function.

Comment: Please note that the Dojo tags are long-deprecated; please consider using the Struts 2 jQuery plugin or just using plain old JS/JQ.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am looking to set an auto refresh after 2 minuter of one page. Please help

Comment: Using Struts2 jQuery plugin I was able to automatically trigger the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Struts2 jQuery plugin I was able to automatically trigger an action call after 5000 milliseconds

This is the code example

```
<sj:div id="div4" href="%{ajaxCall}" updateFreq="5000">
    <s:url id="ajaxCall" value="UpdateAction!methodName"/>
</sj:div>
```

Regards